# SQL Server - Measuring impact of CTFP change....at server level

Tags: sql-server, configuration, cpu

I have a SQL Server 2017 server and CTFP has been set to 5 since it was set up. I'm considering changing it.

I'm comfortable in monitoring the impact of this change at the individual query level - despite the stored procedures being encrypted, I can still monitor them using Query Store.

What I'm less sure of is monitoring throughput on the instance as a whole. The workload of the server is OLTP - lots of very small, mainly write transactions. I already monitor metrics such as batch requests/sec, however, this tells me the number of requests RECEIVED, rather than completed.

I want to monitor the number of transactions being COMPLETED per second to make sure that overall throughput is maintained or improved by the CTFP change. I don't think Batch requests/sec really tells me this (I could be wrong).

What is the best metric/approach for me to use to prove how overall throughput has changed?

Comment: Are you sure parallelism is a bottleneck on your server to begin with?...i.e. did you confirm that the majority of the queries on your server are using parallelism and / or parallelism is one of your top wait types?

Comment: Yes, CXPACKET waits account for > 50%. I can see a number of queries where parallelism is hurting the performance. There are also a number of queries that are regularly hitting a DOP of 12, so am also looking at reducing this to 6 (based on MS's standard calculation).

Comment: And you've confirmed it's many parallel queries that are the issue not one or a few being hogs? There's kind of two questions baked into your post: an indirect question on measuring the success of increasing `CTFP`, which one way would be to monitor if your parallelism wait types decrease to a more reasonable number (as I'm sure you already know). Your direct question on "*What is the best metric/approach for me to use to prove how overall throughput has changed?*" is what I'm sure you're actually interested in. You may want to consider a separate post on maximizing throughput, in general.

Comment: There aren't a huge number of parallel queries. In fact, using a modified version of MJS script (https://michaeljswart.com/2022/01/measure-the-effect-of-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/ ) shows only around 30 results, most of which have a NULL query text because of the encryption.  I don't think it makes sense to leave it at 5, even though only a small number of queries are affected, but accept that there isn't a massive argument for changing it.

Comment: Increasing CTFP will likely reduce CXPACKET waits, but I want to make sure that it isn't at the expense of overall throughput. Some queries will be faster - I know this. However, some of the currently-parallel queries will be slower. I ultimately want to prove that the change doesn't cause an overall reduction in throughput. So yes, how do you monitor throughput based on completed transactions, and not just requests? Apologies if I'm confusing matters.